# Dynamic script file remains out of date

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, dynamic

I'm trying to debug a piece of MVC code, and when I hit a breakpoint, I see it is hit in a dynamic script file named `VMnnn`. I have tried everything, CTRL+F5, clear browser cache with menu, and cleared ASP.NET temp files, stopped IIS Express. Yet the dynamic script file remains out of date with the real script, which is inline in the Razor code for the view.

How can I force this dynamic script file to update? Or, can I find and delete this dynamic file, if it isn't just in memory.

Comment: In your browser (Assuming Chrome): open the `DevTools` (`f12`) and in the `network` tab select disable cache. You need to keep this window open for disable cache to work though.

Comment: Another way would be to append a random query string to the file every time the page loads: `<script src="/path/to/js/file.js?some_random_string></script>`

Comment: Did you add it as a Bundle in the `BundleConfig.RegisterBundles`? When there are changes the framework always makes the scripts unique with an query string parameter.

Comment: @VDWWD No, the script is inline in the Razor partial view, not bundled at all.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn My script isn't loaded from a file reference, it is inline in a partial view, so I can't append anything to the link.

Comment: If you use the ScriptBundle then you won't have that problem. It will update on every build.

Comment: @VDWWD I can't implement bundling - this is a massive legacy project with lots of "magic" going on in the background/infrastructure. Before we had bundling I'm sure this problem was solved some other way.

Comment: Then the suggestion of @GetOffMyLawn can work. Place a query string in the url of the script and make it unique (with a global variable that you increment, or simply generate a unique string every time with Guid or DateTime)

Comment: Have you tried using tools like Postman to make sure that the "dynamic script" really is dynamic? Is there a possibility that for some reason the output script simply remains the same?

Comment: @Mu-TsunTsai In VS, the dynamic script I debug into is named `VMnnn`, and when I make changes to my actual script, the dynamic script never immediately reflects changes until I refresh the page. The script is dynamic.

Comment: @ProfK Just to make sure we're on the same page: of course you need to refresh the page (unless you have a mechanism to reload only the script and not the entire page) for the script to change, but you mean the script doesn't update immediately, and it changes only after a while, perhaps after refreshing the page several times?

Comment: Another important question: do you access the page by GET or POST method?

Comment: @Mu-TsunTsai I'm refreshing the partial view the script is contained in, but yes, the dynamic script didn't update at all for several attempts, and then suddenly it just did. I no longer have this problem, but am leaving the question for others with the same problem. I access the page via GET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a random string via JavaScript using `Math.random()` and converting it to a string (optionally you can then remove the non-word characters that `toString()` generates).

Next We create a script tag dynamically and assign the random string to the query portion of the `src` attribute.

Lasly, we insert the tag into the body or head anyway you would like. `appendChild`, `write`, etc.

```js
// Create a random string
let random = (Math.random() * 10000).toString(12)

// Generate the script tag
let script = document.createElement('script')
script.src = `http://example.com/js/myfile.js?${random}`

// Place the script tag somewhere.
document.body.appendChild(script)
```

Comment: My problem just disappeared, but although my script is not loaded from a static href, but dynamically using a list of scripts in an XML file. Yet, this is the only solid answer I've got, and I've used this technique before with success, so I'm accepting.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the client side's setting, sometimes the client (especially webviews) could cache the page content despite of the fact that the page is supposed to be dynamic, if the page is accessed with the GET method and with the same parameters. Suggestions by others mentioning passing a random GET parameter  could also prevent client caching, but you don't necessarily have control over the client's request. In that case, one thing you may try is to add the following line inside the action method of your controller:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```

Or, you can write an attribute like this:

```
public class NoCacheAttribute : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter {

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) {
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) { }
}
```

And add the `[NoCache]` attribute to whichever controller or action you want. This will notify the client that this page is not supposed to be cached. The client might still ignore this header though, again depending on its settings, but the default behavior of most client should work with this method.